# How can I reload my Chrome extension when it is not possible to do so from chrome://extensions because of my extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm testing out Chrome Extension development and was testing how to do a page redirect through Chrome Extension.

Well it works, but now because of that I can't access the extension settings page.
How do I manually reload/disable the extension? Or do that from the Mac terminal?
My Chrome is pretty much unusable now thanks to my own code.

Thank you!

Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be "How can I reload my Chrome extension when it is not possible to do so from chrome://extensions because of my extension?"

A possible answer is:

1. Press Shift + Esc to open the task manager (or click on the hamburger menu -> More tools -> Task manager).
2. Select your extension.
3. Click on the "End process" button.
4. Now you can visit chrome://extensions and reload your extension in the usual way.

The previous only works if there is an extension process, not if your extension is purely a content script extension. If you still want to use the above method, you can force an extension process to become visible by opening `chrome-extension://[extension id here]/manifest.json` in a new tab.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks Rob!

Comment: @teepusink Could you then update the question's title to match your real question (from your second paragraph) and my answer? Otherwise future visitors might be a bit disappointed when they try to look for the answer as stated in the title.